# How to say "sexist" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

Today in class we were discussing a dialogue and one student wanted to say that pne phrase is "sexist". Our teacher wasn't able to provide an answer for that, also because she doesn't speak much English. Is there a word for "sexist" in Chinese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sexist as a noun is "性别歧视". For example, "不许男人当护士是**性别歧视**" (Not allowing men to be nurses is **sexist**)

A sexist person is called "性别歧视者", for example, "他是一个 **性别歧视者**" (he is a **sexist**)

Sexist as an adjective is "性别歧视的", for example, "**性别歧视的**观点" (**sexist** view)

These terms all sound very technical, the more commonly used terms would be 大男人主义 or 大男人主义者  (We don't hear people say 大女人主义 or 大女人主义者 is a fact, but also technically a sexist view)

Answer (score 0):

There is no word for word, the closest should be "性別主義者", a person that against others based on their sex, or sexual orientation.

Answer (score 0):

A racist is 种族主义者
A racist remark is then 种族主义言论

sexism can be translated as 性别主义

"是指根据性别差异认为不同性别的个体有优劣之分的**偏见**。最常见的表现是“大男子主义”和对女性的歧视。"

偏见：slanting look, i.e. prejudice

a sexist would then be 性别主义者
a sexist remark would then be 性别主义言论

基于人的性别而将人视为优劣。
Judge a person's merits on the basis of gender.